# Postgres Materialized View update every 1 minute?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a postgres View which is a join of almost 3-4 tables. Even after adding indexes I find the query to be slow on 100k rows.

I am thinking of changing it to a materialized view which is updated every 1 minute. Does it make sense to do something like that?

Comment: Why don't you try to optimize your query? That's the real problem. Please show us your query and the results from EXPLAIN ANALYZE at http://explain.depesz.com

Comment: @FrankHeikens http://explain.depesz.com/s/pa4q it is the explain.

The query : http://pastebin.com/xgmkEj1h

Comment: Could you replace * by the columnames, including the table names? I have no idea where a1 or a2 is related, it's just a piece of text without any meaning. By the way, you could use a bit more work_mem to avoid this issue: Sort Method: external merge Disk: 9216kB.

Comment: @FrankHeikens here is the full query : http://socrates.io/#8FHUC89

Comment: When is_active must be true, the JOIN between expressions_contents and expressions_sources should be a INNER JOIN instead of a LEFT JOIN. All columns in the JOIN-conditions should be indexed, not sure if you did that already. After changing the LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN, could you please post the results from EXPLAIN ANALYZE again?

Comment: @FrankHeikens : I have already indexed all the join conditions already. I changed the left join to inner join as suggested by you : http://explain.depesz.com/s/Ahb